# Как грамотно создать указатель на protected метод надкласса?

Tags: c++, ооп, шаблоны-с++, наследование

```
template <typename T1, typename T2>
class A
{
    protected:
    T1 methodA(T2 a){};
}

template <typename TB1, typename TB2>
class B: public A<TB1, TB2>
{
    public:
    /* здесь мне нужно создать methodA, 
    но публичный, возможно с другим названием, 
    скорее всего через указатель */
}
```

Соответственно, подскажите пожалуйста как это грамотно сделать?
Т.е. на месте комментария в классе B мне нужно получить указатель, например methidB, на метод methodA класса А.

Comment: Уточните, что значит создать метод через указатель??

Comment: Т.е. на месте комментария в классе B мне нужно получить указатель, например methodB, на метод methodA класса А. Дело в том, что methodA в классе B есть через наследование от класса A, но наследование через protected делает его приватным, а мне он нужен публично.

Comment: Во-первых, если он protected, то для чего-то это нужно, не считаете, что ломать инкапсуляцию - плохая идея?) Но если очень нужно, то что мешает сделать methodB, который внутри будет вызывать methodA с такими же аргументами? Также вы можете сделать это при помощи shadowing, как внизу, но это чревато проблемами с архитектурой и трудноотлаживаемыми ошибками

Comment: Указатель здесь противопоказан. Указатель позволил бы вызывать метод предка в обход метода потомка, а это нарушение инкапсуляции. Просто вызывайте один метод из другого. Кстати, при обсуждении внутренностей софта на c++ принято конкретизировать вид метода – функция-член.

Comment: Он протектед в предке. Вот есть класс инструментов – телескопы. А есть другой класс инструментов – астрографы. Астрограф определён как телескоп, предназначенный только для съёмки. Очевидно, что у астрографа должен торчать наружу выбор выдержки. А вот окуляра основной оптической системы у астрографа, наоборот, нет. Есть ещё один класс инструментов – гибриды астрографов с классическими телескопами. Очевидно, что у этих инструментов торчат наружу именно окуляры основных оптических систем. И выбор выдержки столь же доступен пользователю.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Непонятно... Вы хотите чего-то такого?

```
template <typename T1, typename T2>
class A
{
    protected:
        T1 methodA(T2){ cout << "A::method A\n"; return T1{}; };
};

template <typename TB1, typename TB2>
class B: public A<TB1,TB2>
{
public:
    TB1 methodA(TB2 t)
    {
        return A<TB1,TB2>::methodA(t);
    }
    /* здесь мне нужно создать methodA, 
    но публичный, возможно с другим названием, 
    скорее всего через указатель */
};

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    B<int,int> b;
    b.methodA(0);
}
```